# Which is better in codeigniter? Adding a function in a helper or adding a function in an extended base class

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-helpers

In a codeigniter project i have to do some set of stuff in one than one controller. 
I code all that stuff in a function and now i need to call whenever necessary.
i think Writing this function in more than one controller is not good. 
i have 2 options,

1. create a helper and write these function in that and include the helper in necessary controllers.
2. Since i have extended CI base controller (My_Controller) and most of my controllers are extended that controller, i can write this function to my base controller also.

I have confused which one is better, right way?
Which one will speed up the process?
Is the second way slows the site?

Comment: This is pretty much the reason the ability to extend the core classes exists. I'm not sure where the confusion is, especially if you already have the MY_Controller written.

Comment: Yes. Reading others answers and comparing my code i think MY_controller is the best option as it does not need any inclusion in my current code. If i put the needed stuff in library or helper i need to load them in my other controllers. i think by considering performance and speed MY_controller is better.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical for all intents and purposes.

Using a helper allows you to make the code portable, so you can use it in other projects, or to be called from anywhere in the code base, in the case of a formatting function for example

If you were planning to put it in a controller, then MY_Controller is best bet

Answer (score 1):

Just to help you on you endeavor what i do is: (this is just me)

1. If i need to use something in the views, i use a `helper` a custom one or built in.
2. If i want to do something on a controller that other controller will be using too and  don't want it to mess up or crowd my controller i use a `library` (pretty much you can use a `helper` but i chose to use a library)
3. If i want to load lets say a method, to affect Globally or some of the controller i use the `base controller`. (you could also use `helper` or `library`)

The key is you are not restricted to one, choose the best that suits you, as the saying goes, there are many ways to skin a cat, but please don't skin a cat..